# Best way to load a function library

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is it common practice to simply use the `load` function at the top of lisp code files to bring in functions defined elsewhere, similar to the `#include` directive in C/C++?

i.e.

```
(load "math_functions.lisp")
(load "string_processing.lisp")
```

Or are there other more common ways to share functions between files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you can just `load` files into your "master" file, but the more common and actually convenient way to go is to use the ASDF facility.

They way I do this is together with Quicklisp to create a directory for your project in the `~/quicklisp/local-projects` directory and there put the `.asd` file together with sources.

You might also find [this guide to Quickproject](http://xach.livejournal.com/278047.html) useful.

Answer (score 3):

Usually libraries use some tools that allows you to compile and load the library correctly. If the library is quite big, then it's hard to load it without knowledge of the internal dependencies. One of such tools is `ASDF`([asdf article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Another_System_Definition_Facility)), that is the standard for Common Lisp.

Also if you develop some package with several files you can use `asdf` to describe dependencies and relations between files.